# Light PHP database-driven framework

Tags: php, sql, web-applications, frontend

I'm looking for a framework that has the following characteristics:

- Preferably PHP-driven
- Preferably FOSS
- Light, simple
- Has a concentration on quick prototyping rather than complex security models
- Is able to semi-automatically generate HTML forms for a GUI interface to an existing SQL database, given some DDL, without modifying its structure
- DBMS-agnostic, ie., works with PostgreSQL just as well as MySQL

I have a reasonable amount of PHP and SQL experience, but in this case I don't want to go through the (repetitive) trouble of making the forms and login system myself. I'd also prefer not to have to learn an entire new language just to get this done (ie. Ruby).

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which framework for a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490694/which-framework-for-a-project)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A lightweight application framework for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424/a-lightweight-application-framework-for-php) as well

Comment: Different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490694/which-framework-for-a-project because in this case I prefer not to learn an entire new language but rather adopt a framework only; and the needs of the client are such that the GUI must be formed based on the database and not the other way around.

Comment: Different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424/a-lightweight-application-framework-for-php as that's much more generic of a question.

Answer (score 2):

[Lithium](http://lithify.me/) and [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) are PHP 5.3 based and soon to be released if you want namespaces and closures. Symfony is probably a bit large for your sake, but I'd still recommend you look at it. (It plays well with Zend and tons of other stuff.)

Else try [Solar](http://www.solarphp.com/) or [YII](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

There are others, e.g. CakePHP (by the authors of Lithium), CodeIgnitor, etc. But they're becoming a bit old imho.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too lightweight, considering the features you mentioned, but anyways it's a really nice micro framework to know about: Limonade, http://www.limonade-php.net It's super fast when it comes to prototyping stuff, but it lacks the M in MVC. Don't be afraid to mix some little libraries that suit your needs to form a full featured lightweight MVC framework.

Comment: For lightweight proto-typing projects I tend to use [Slim](www.slimframework.com) which like limonade lacks the Model aspect but this can be made up for with [idiorm](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/).

Answer (score 1):

I've been in Zend-Framework for about a year. For your needs, the Zend-Framework is totally overkill. However I've not worked with the CakePHP-Framework, but I read through their introduction once or twice. Since CakePHP seems to be much lighter than Zend-Framework I would suggest that you take a look at CakePHP:

http://cakephp.org/

I think they also provide a console-driven tool, which can generate views, actions and forms fitting your database-tables.

Comment: This looks great. It seems that `bake.php` is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

zend framework is good also codeigniter and cakephp